# Node not showing

Tags: 7, theming

Hi all I am facing problem with bootstrap  theme 
I am unable to show  node  when I edit the node.all data shows node/edit path 
but not in node

> I don,t know what is this issue  problem with bootstrap them I am
>   using sub theme   and make my custom template  but same problem with
>   parent theme  please give me suggestion for this  thanks in advance

Comment: did you see any error message?

Comment: I check there is no error but on images that is static path is like node/site/all  and url is node/%

Comment: check  http://apetrailportfolio.com/Development/InfinityPups/node/1 currently i add block for about us page node content not  showing

Comment: What happens if you (temporary) switch to some other theme (bartik or something)? Similar problem/scenario?

Comment: then its working fine

Comment: Is the "Main page content" placed inside a region at admin/structure/block?

Comment: still having this issue?

Comment: @ undersound  yes  its  a block   , currently  node not showing  so i have to make block

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me before , first check the themes setting and make sure you edit nodes in your default admin theme , then check you have no errors in your bootstrap templates , if it still displays a blank screen while you try to edit try deactivating bootstrap theme